# Views sort criteria by term for advertising

Tags: views

I have view displaying 3 types of content with, one of the filter criteria is taxonomy term for city.

I would like to give user option to pay to be first on the list for a specific city(term), and afterwards the results would go as usual (sorted by date of creation).

Comment: I'm not positive, but if you add a term reference field to whatever content type serves as the advertisement, you should be able to sort it by term with [this approach](https://www.drupal.org/node/1387130#comment-5405974). Be sure to rearrange your sort options so the default 'Content: Post date (desc)' occurs last.

Comment: Are you asking about whole process? Or only about sorting? If about whole, your question might be to broad. If about during, then how are you marking your users as "paid" and how are you associate this with cities?